# Booting a QorIQ PowerPC firmware in Qemu

Tags: qemu, u-boot, powerpc, firmware

I have a QorIQ (P2041) processor based IoT device firmware. I have uBoot, Kernel and initrd ramdisk. Whatever I do with `qemu-system-ppc` I can't get it to work. I suspect that `qemu-system-ppc` doesn't support QorIQ processors. Is there anyway for me to load and boot this firmware in Qemu or any other emulator?

Answer (score 0):

U-Boot has configuration file qemu-ppce500_defconfig. You should be able to run the U-Boot built with this configuration using command

qemu-system-ppc -nographic -bios u-boot -M ppce500

The CPU can be specified via the -cpu parameter as e500mc.

To run your kernel it will need drivers for the hardware provided by the emulated machine like the E1000 network card and the NS16550 console.

Use the fdt command of U-Boot to get an overview of the available devices in the emulated machine.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to do that but seems like it doesn't like my u-boot file. I get "qemu: could not load firmware".  Header of my uboot img file starts with AA 55 AA 55 and 100 bytes or so below shows VU-Boot 2012.11-svn.... etc. Do I have to trim some of the top of the img file?

Answer (score 0):

Firmware binaries are generally very closely tied to the hardware they're built to run on -- they make assumptions about what hardware is available, what addresses in memory it can be found at, and so on. You need to use a firmware blob that corresponds to the hardware you're asking QEMU to emulate. Since QEMU doesn't emulate whatever your random IoT device is, you need to use a u-boot which matches the hardware QEMU actually has (as for example suggested in Xypron's answer).

Once you have booting firmware, you will likely still find you have exactly the same problem with the kernel -- it is built to run on one bit of hardware, and you're trying to run it on something different, and this simply won't work.

Comment: Ok but I have all files, I don't need the hardware things to work which obviously it won't I just want to be able to run an debug a single binary inside of it. Can I maybe try to run the binary alone in Qemu?

Comment: Yeah, using just userspace or just a particular binary and libs from the device on top of a kernel that is built to work with QEMU is a more likely-to-succeed route I think.